# Multiple E-mail preview

Tags: vb.net, email, preview

I need to send multiple e-mails but I want to check content before sending them.
To do this I tryed by using `WebBrowser` and a `MsgBox` confirmation but I can't scroll the `WebBrowser` as long as the MsgBox is displayed.
I also tryed by using `WebBrowser` into another Form but I wasn't able to pause-resume the loop for sending e-mails.
Can anyone suggest me the correct way? (if possible with a sample code or a tutorial link)